# Are results significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, sample

I am fairly new to statistics so I am unsure which statistical test I should use to test which of the datasets shows a better result. The data looks something like this

Variant A: { 3, 7, 10}

Variant B:{ 2, 3, 6 }

After correcting for outliers, can I just use the average of these numbers to determine a winner? How do I determine that I have sufficient data which of these sets shows a significantly better result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data are independent observations, you can use the Mann-Whitney U-test if you can't assume a normal distribution. If the data follows a normal distribution you can use the independent samples t-test. If the data are paired you can use similar but different tests for increased sensitivity.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!